# How does this definition of a computable function work?

Tags: functions, computability, turing-machines

I have the definitions of computable (from my class notes) over here:

> $f$ is computable if there is a computable function $\hat{f}:\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$ such that, for all $n,r \in \Bbb N$
> $$
> \left |\hat{f}(n,r) - f(n) \right|\leq2^{-r}.
> $$

I come from a non-math background, so could someone break it down for me? I understand what $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ are. I am just mainly confused with the expression above.

Comment: Where did you find that definition?  And what do you already know about the subject?  Do we need to explain what N and Q are?  Do we need to explain the notation, or just the idea behind the statement?  Do you know what a function is?  You're not giving us any information that will help us give you the explanation you want at the level you need.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thank you. But I am trying to understand the above math definition.

Comment: ''f is computable if there is a computable function f^". The general definition of computability refers to the function f^. This is what a computable function is. In your text, another function f is defined to be ''computable'' and it refers to a computable function f^

Comment: What about the 2^(-r)

Comment: $f$ is obviously any random function, while $\hat f$ needs to be based on a finite algorithm, with or without loops. /// $2^{-r}$ is a null sequence, meaning that $\hat f$ gets $r$ bits after the dot of $f$ right. /// The major point here is the uniformity in $n$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! I am a little lost on these terms on though - "null sequence", "r bits", "dot of f right". Also what uniformity in n mean?

Comment: "null sequence" - converges to zero; "bits" - like decimals, only in binary; "after the dot" - in the non-integer or fractional part of a number; "right" - getting something right; "uniform in $n$" - the same way for all $n$

Comment: For instance, you did not tell what other sources apart from your class notes you have consulted. On such non-political themes wikipedia tends to be quite reliable, if not always correct in all finer nuances. This should at least give you some more keywords surrounding the topic that you might need clarified.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. I will definitely keep that in mind when posting other questions. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's consider $f(n) = \frac{7n}5$.  Whatever “computable” means, this function should have that property.  For example, if we put in $n=2$ the computer can print out `2.8` which is the exact answer.

Now let's consider $f(n) = \frac{7n}3$.  Here if we put in $n=2$ the answer would look like `4.6666…` and the computer can't emit an exact answer.  But that is really just a quibble, right?  A notion of computability that depends on these unimportant representation details, and which said that $\frac{7n}5$  was computable but  $\frac{7n}3$ wasn't, would be silly.  In practice we don't care that $\frac{14}5$ is a terminating decimal and $\frac{14}3$ isn't.  But why not?

Decimal approximations can't perfectly represent most numbers, even simple numbers like $\frac{14}3$.  But it doesn't matter, because they can represent all real numbers with *arbitrarily good* accuracy.  If we want to know the value of $\frac{14}3$ with an error of no more than $\frac1{10}$, we can do that; it's `4.6`.  If we want the error to be less than $\frac1{1000000}$ we can do that with decimal fractions also; it's `4.6666666`.

We'll say that some mathematical function $f$ is computable if there is a corresponding computation, $\hat f$, which can compute $f$ to any desired degree of accuracy.  You tell it how many decimal places of accuracy you need; that's $r$, and then tell it to calculate $f(n)$.  It may not be able to calculate $f(n)$ exactly, but it can calculate it accurate to  $r$ places, so that its output differs from the actual value of $f(n)$ by no more than $10^{-r}$.  Then if you decide you need better accuracy later, you tell it a different $r$ and it can work harder and come up with a better answer.

So we say $f$ is computable if there is an approximation function $\hat f$ that computes $f$ to any desired degree of accuracy:

$$\lvert \hat f(n, r) - f(n) \rvert \le 10^{-r}.$$

$f$ is the function we 're approximating, and $\hat f$ is the computer program that approximates it: given an argument $n$ and a precision $r$, it computes an approximate value of $f(n)$ that is accurate to at least $r$ decimal places.

With this definition all the usual arithmetic functions are computable.  Observe that while the output of $\hat f$ is required to be a rational number, the output of the original $f$ need not always be rational. For example, $f(n) = \sqrt n$ is computable.  What happens when you try to compute $\sqrt 2$?  There's no way to write out the ⸢exact⸣ answer; what would that even mean?  But it doesn't matter, because all we ever really want is to compute approximate square roots of $2$ such as `1.4` or `1.4142` or `1.41421356237309504880` or whatever.  [People have been computing square roots in *that* sense for thousands of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Also with this definition, the output format of the algorithm can be left unspecified.  Does the $\hat f$ print out its result in decimal digits or in binary digits? It shouldn't matter.  What if it wants to print out a rational approximation like $\frac{202030}{142857}$?  That should also be acceptable.  The definition of computability doesn't care; it just says that $\hat f$ has to be able to emit some rational number, in *some* form, that is sufficiently close to the correct answer.

Instead of measuring accuracy in decimal digits, the definition you have is using binary digits, so it has $2^{-r}$ instead of $10^{-r}$.  But there is no conceptual difference, and the two definitions are equivalent.  (You prove this.)

If any part of this doesn't make sense, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4423915/65502) already outlines what the definition probably had in mind, however I consider it important to note that the definition is incomplete (which might explain your confusion):

1. It defines computability of functions with domain ℕ (natural numbers).
2. It presumes a definition of the computability of functions with domain ℕ×ℕ (pairs of natural numbers).
3. Since the domains are different, you cannot work recursively, i.e. you cannot determine computability for determining Point 2 using Point 1.
4. Even if it did work recursively, there is no starting point of functions that are defined as computable by other means.

A complete definition using the same idea would be something like (with $\mathbf{n}=(n_1,n_2,…,n_m)$ being an arbitrary tuple of natural numbers):

> $f:ℕ^m→ℚ$ is *computable* if one of the following holds:
>
> 1. The value of $f(\mathbf{n})$ can be determined exactly by applying finitely many standard arithmetic operations (+, −, ×, ÷) to $n_1,n_2,…,n_m$.
> 2. There is a computable function $\hat{f}: ℕ^m×ℕ → ℚ$ such that, for all $\mathbf{n},r ∈ ℕ^m×ℕ$:
>    $$\left| \hat{f}(\mathbf{n},r) - f(\mathbf{n}) \right | \leq2^{-r}.$$

Here the first part defines things that are “trivially computable”.
Mind that there are many possibilities for defining this, depending on the application and how deep you want to go into the details of computer architecture.
The second part is the same as in the question, except for admitting arbitrary tuples of natural numbers as input.
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4423915/65502) explains the motivation behind this in detail.